# How to use mutexs and processes?

Tags: c++, windows, mutex

I have the "philosophers problem" to do, I need to use mutex as the lock (sticks) and five different proccesses to represent the philosofers, But I faced a few problems.

- I dont know if the mutexes need to be in the file where I creates the proccesses and send them to the .exe that feed each philosofer with the given sticks, or in the .exe file where I feed the philosofers like I did with the switch case condition.
- I dont know how do I send the parameters (philosofer number / mutexes) or more then one parameter to the main function in the .exe file.

**UPDATED MY CODE!!**

this is the main I run and create processes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE stick1;
HANDLE stick2;
HANDLE stick3;
HANDLE stick4;
HANDLE stick5;

int main()
{

    stick1 = CreateMutexA(NULL, FALSE, "stick1");
    stick1 = CreateMutexA(NULL, FALSE, "stick2");
    stick1 = CreateMutexA(NULL, FALSE, "stick3");
    stick1 = CreateMutexA(NULL, FALSE, "stick4");
    stick1 = CreateMutexA(NULL, FALSE, "stick5");

    LPSTR cmdArgs1 = const_cast <char*>("mutex.exe 1");
    LPSTR cmdArgs2 = const_cast <char*>("mutex.exe 2");
    LPSTR cmdArgs3 = const_cast <char*>("mutex.exe 3");
    LPSTR cmdArgs4 = const_cast <char*>("mutex.exe 4");
    LPSTR cmdArgs5 = const_cast <char*>("mutex.exe 5");

    STARTUPINFOA si1;
    STARTUPINFOA si2;
    STARTUPINFOA si3;
    STARTUPINFOA si4;
    STARTUPINFOA si5;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi1;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi2;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi3;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi4;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi5;


    ZeroMemory(&si1, sizeof(si1));
    si1.cb = sizeof(si1);
    ZeroMemory(&pi1, sizeof(pi1));
    
    ZeroMemory(&si2, sizeof(si2));
    si2.cb = sizeof(si2);
    ZeroMemory(&pi2, sizeof(pi2));

    ZeroMemory(&si3, sizeof(si3));
    si3.cb = sizeof(si3);
    ZeroMemory(&pi3, sizeof(pi3));

    ZeroMemory(&si4, sizeof(si4));
    si4.cb = sizeof(si4);
    ZeroMemory(&pi4, sizeof(pi4));

    ZeroMemory(&si5, sizeof(si5));
    si5.cb = sizeof(si5);
    ZeroMemory(&pi5, sizeof(pi5));

    

    BOOL p1 = CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdArgs1, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si1, &pi1);
    BOOL p2 = CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdArgs2, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si2, &pi2);
    BOOL p3 = CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdArgs3, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si3, &pi3);
    BOOL p4 = CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdArgs4, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si4, &pi4);
    BOOL p5 = CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdArgs5, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si5, &pi5);

    
    if (p1 && p2 && p3 && p4 && p5)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi1.hProcess, INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(pi2.hProcess, INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(pi3.hProcess, INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(pi4.hProcess, INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(pi5.hProcess, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(pi1.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi1.hThread);

        CloseHandle(pi2.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi2.hThread);
        
        CloseHandle(pi3.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi3.hThread);

        CloseHandle(pi4.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi4.hThread);
        
        CloseHandle(pi5.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi5.hThread);
    }
}
```

and this is the .exe file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>

#define TIMES_TO_EAT 1000000
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE rightStick;
    HANDLE leftStick;

    int i = 0;
    char id = argv[1][0]; // supposed to be the number of the philosofer
    char rightS[] = "stick";
    char leftS[] = "stick";
    char leftStickCalc = (char)((int)id - 1);

    if (id == '1')
    {
        leftStickCalc = '5';
    }

    strncat(rightS, &id, 1);
    strncat(leftS, &leftStickCalc, 1);

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    while (i < TIMES_TO_EAT)
    {
        rightStick = OpenMutexA(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, LPSTR(rightS));
        if (rightStick != NULL)
        {
            leftStick = OpenMutexA(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, LPSTR(leftS));
            if (leftStick != NULL)
            {
                i++;
                ReleaseMutex(rightStick);
                ReleaseMutex(leftStick);
                if (i == TIMES_TO_EAT)
                {
                    CloseHandle(rightStick);
                    CloseHandle(leftStick);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ReleaseMutex(rightStick);
            }
        }
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> time = end - start;
    printf("philosopher %c finished eat %d times in %.2f seconds\n", id, i, time.count());
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const_cast <char*>` is not C

Comment: I am using visual studio so its a c++ project technically, thats why it let me use it I guess

Comment: You should create the mutexes in the main program - before creating the processes, then in the philosophers program, open the mutexes with `OpenMutex()`

Comment: Note: you have a lot of repeated code that can be eliminated using arrays (c) or vectors (c++). Also, each philosopher only needs to open 2 mutexes (left and right) not all 5.

Comment: Neither is `<iostream>` or `<chrono>` C.  If you *intend* for your code to be written in C++ then that's fine, but tag the question correctly (c++, not c).  If you are supposed to be writing in C, however, then you need to fix multiple things.  I don't use VS, but doesn't it have a way to specify projects as C rather than C++?  I sure thought it did.  At minimum, naming your source files with a `.c` extension might help.

Comment: so I need to send the two relevant mutexes to the proccess as parameter and open them in the .exe file?

Comment: No, you don't "send" them. The main program "creates" them and the other program "opens" them. You could send the names the program is to use. See: [Using Named Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-named-objects)

Comment: Could you please remove all the redundancy from your code? It heavily violates the DRY principle and I'm not willing to read all that code and check for typos in each single branch. Use a vector to store your objects instead of giving each variable an individual name.

Comment: I updated my code. Please check that out

Comment: In windows word you usually use threads and not processes to handle this kind of problem: all threads will share the same memory space (i.e. the will see and work on the same variables) and you can use other object (e.g. critical section) to synchronize threads access to a variable.
You'll need a single process with multiple threads. Threads and concurrent variable access are more or less hard to handle, but anyway easier than handling different processes IMHO

Comment: yea I did it already and it was easy but now I need to do it with mutex and procces

Comment: a) Don't call `CloseHandle` in the 2nd program - the main program should close the mutexes. b) Don't change your question as it invalidates any previous comments/answers.